# How to loop through entries by importance?

Tags: entries

I have a channel of entries I'd like to loop through by order of importance on a scale of 1-5 with 5 being the most important and appearing first.

I tried to achieve this using a radio button field called importance and if else statements like:

```
{# List most important entries first #}
{% if entry.importance == "5" %}

    <li class="deal">
        <div class="brand-image-wrapper">
            {% if entry.logo | length %}
                {% for asset in entry.logo %}
                    <img class="grayscale" src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="info">
            <h2 class="title">{{ entry.companyName }}</h2>
            <p>{{ entry.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </li>

    {% elseif entry.importance == "4" %}

        <li class="deal">
            <div class="brand-image-wrapper">
                {% if entry.logo | length %}
                    {% for asset in entry.logo %}
                        <img class="grayscale" src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <h2 class="title">{{ entry.companyName }}</h2>
                <p>{{ entry.description }}</p>
            </div>
        </li>

        etc...
```

But this isn't very DRY and this lists the entries but they are still ordered by date. Is it possible to use .order with a field to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `.order` with any custom field, an example is below.

`craft.entries.section( 'sectionHandle' ).order( 'customFieldHandle' )`

For more info see the docs
https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#order

Comment: I've tried .order('importance') but that shows the order from 1-5. So I tried .order('importance desc') which does show from 5-1 but also reverses the order showing the oldest entries first which I don't want. Is there a way to have 5-1 and newest first? Thanks

Comment: You can sort by multiple fields in asc/desc order using `.order( 'importance desc', 'postDate desc' )`